# How to get next and previous element of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iterator, iteration

For a sample trading app i have an array, with trading pair symbols. And i want to fetch updates, but do it sequentially, eg:

```js
var pairList = ['BTCUSD', 'ETHBTC', 'ETHUSD'];
var currentPair = 0; // now pointing, that next time fetcher would fetch 'BTCUSD' pair
var candlesData = [];

update_current_pair = () {
  // for simplicity imagine that fetch io completes instantly, but it ALSO changes pairList
  candlesData[currentPair] = fetch_data_from_server_for_pair(currentPair);

  // pairList is changed, for example now 'BTCUSD' pair is removed.
  pairList = ['ETHBTC', 'ETHUSD'];

  // then i usually do:
  currentPair++; // increment
  currentPair %= pairList.length; // modulo
  // but OOPS! i just skipped 'ETHBTC' pair!

  setTimeout(update_current_pair, 1000);
}

// start fetcher
update_current_pair();
```

How can i not skip 'ETHBTC' pair?

---

Sample code: https://repl.it/@krieviedkoKtulk/jsasyncissue

desired:

```
updating BTCUSD
updated BTCUSD
updating ETHBTC
updated ETHBTC
updating ETHUSD
updated ETHUSD
updating ETHBTC
updated  ETHBTC
```

observed:

```
updating BTCUSD
updated ETHBTC <- data from BTCUSD is put to ETHBTC by an error
updating ETHUSD <- fetching ETHBTC is skipped, but proceed to next ETHUSD
updated ETHUSD
updating ETHBTC
updated ETHBTC
updating ETHUSD
updated ETHUSD
```

Comment: Delete `pairList = ['ETHBTC', 'ETHUSD'];` that line

Comment: Your code works fine. There is no skipping. Can you make a working code example?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz ahaha, great joke :D

Comment: just use array a bit more elegantly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: @Ahmad sample code link added to question

Comment: Your sample code works fine. It is looping through USD and BTC. What is the expected output?

Comment: @Ahmad added desired and observed outputs

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the `setTimeout()` from within the `update_current_pair()` function, just make a `setInterval()` to begin and you will have the desired output.

So remove the line `setTimeout(update_current_pair, 1000);` from within `update_current_pair()` and make the original function call `setInterval(update_current_pair, 1000);`

```
update_current_pair = () => {
console.log('update called');
  console.log("updating " + pairList[currentPair]);
  // for simplicity imagine that fetch io completes instantly, but it ALSO changes pairList
  fetch_data_from_server_for_pair( () => {
      console.log("updated " + pairList[currentPair]);
      currentPair++; 
      currentPair %= pairList.length;
  } );
}

setInterval(update_current_pair, 1000);
```

Comment: now imagine that a fetching process inside fetch_data_from_server_for_pair() takes more than 1000ms (for example its overloaded server with narrow channel) It will issue an request, and soon it will issue another request, while still being waiting first response. Over time this will lead to overflow..

Comment: @xakepp35 yeah sure, he should probably be using promises but it seemed out of the scope of his question

Comment: The scheme is a bit more complex. Idea is as follows: First start fetching loop, inside which do "fetch pair, when response arrived - fetch another immediately. Fetch delay is unknown and may be either instant ,or of order of seconds. Process pairs, until all pairs from array are fetched". Then (after loop) make a delay for 1 second and start that fetching loop again. That's fetching logic. BUT it have to consider that array may be changed (cleared or populated) by external event.

Comment: I just omited this to single between fetching each pair,and timeout to artificially model array changing problem.

Comment: I don't know, lol. Kinda seems like you might be overthinking it a bit

Comment: Maybe, but i want to be safe. What is general multithreaded advice, when iterating array, while another thread could remove or add elements? This seems to be typical task

Comment: You're talking about parts of his code you can't see here... You don't necessarily know that the data he is receiving has any possibility of changing. My assumption was from the way he originally approached the problem that it wouldn't

Comment: His? "Yours", you meant? Heh, I accidentally managed to be the question author :-) And told some details, why i omited them. There are several tricky things about server, but only that i need was iterating over array, where iteration is async, and array may be changed, meanwhile iterating

Comment: Ahh ok sorry, I thought you were just some random guy poking holes in my code. When you say that the array may be changed or cleared by an external event, which array are you talking about? The array on the front end or from the server?

Comment: @xakepp35 take a look at this: https://codepen.io/katiedotson-the-decoder/pen/XyxZxw?editors=0012

Comment: Your code **does not remove** elements. Imagine a web page, for example, where user can edit array - at any(unknown) time he may add or remove some elements. Program goal is just to iterate this list in an infinite loop, while doing some fetches from remote server.

Comment: But when list content is changed the iterator index becomes invalid. This leads to 2 potential errors: 1. When i am requesting element #37 and waiting response from server it could be deleted, and array will be shifted and now element #37 is whole different story.2. I dont know how to introduce order: look at Question: there are code link and *observed* and *desired* behaviours.

Comment: Ohhh ok. That is an interesting problem. Could you post another question that more directly addresses this problem?